# Indicate when a user has unaccepted a massive number of answers to their questions

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, vandalism

We've recently gotten a flag on Stack Overflow indicating that a user has gone through and unaccepted every single one of their answers.

While this is perfectly OK and *allowed* by the system, it could be an indicator of vandalism, and right now, it's not something that's easily detectable.

That said, I'd like to see two things.  First, there should be a way to see that a user unaccepted an answer in their activity.  We can see *accepts*, but not unaccepts.

Note that we can look at the reputation and see the -2 applied for unaccepting an answer (and we can see a bunch of them in a row), but we have a specific tab in the activity section of our profiles to show our accepts, there's no reason we shouldn't have the same duplication of information for the unaccept case.

If a user unaccepts a number of answers in a short period of time, I'd like to see a flag in the moderator queue indicating that there were a number of unaccepts in a short period of time, just like we have for edits and deletes.

Finally, as per [Sha Dow Wiz Ard's suggestion in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130799/indicate-when-a-user-has-unaccepted-a-massive-number-of-answers-to-their-questio#comment359573_130799), there should be a rate limit on how many unaccepts you can do per day, as per the delete rate limit.

Comment: That most certainly sounds peculiar...

Comment: I would go even further - as unaccept should be rare thing under normal circumstances, it should be limited to only a few per day same way that there is limit on deletions for example. (as far as I know there is such limit)

Comment: would we see if one of our answers has been unaccepted by someone in our history.. I don't know if i am confused or what but i think i had an answer unaccepted due to a new solution being available but it now looks like it was never accepted in the first place. as it goes i was interested to see the new solution so would have liked to know anyway.

Comment: @Lix I for one am not surprised - user got frustrated for some reason (there can be many: downvotes on his posts, lack of answer he expected to, annoying user bashing him etc etc) and go on a rampage. Most just delete their posts or at least try to..

Comment: @gordatron yes it should be visible in the reputation tab in the profile, you will see -15 in red background with *unaccept* as the description and the time when it happened.

Comment: @sha - that sounds like **a lot** of work... but... rage quit will make you do silly things :P

Comment: @gordatron for example, you unaccepted an answer on July 18, 2010 so it's now clearly visible in the [author profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/12895/craig-trader?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=6) under that day. [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aou9h.png)

Comment: Surely an unaccept would show a -2 in the users reputation profile.

Comment: @chr - `-15` perhaps...

Comment: @ChrisF - I am certain it will, but the system will not notify moderators if a bunch of these was made in a short amount of time.

Comment: @Lix - the -15 will be on the reputation page of the **answerwer**. This is on the reputation page of the **asker**.

Comment: @Lix - No -15 to the person whose answer was unaccepted. -2 for the person who did the unaccepting (reveting the +2 from accepting an answer)

Comment: @Oded - I agree that the moderator flag is required. I was just asking if the -2 currently appears on the askers profile page.

Comment: @ChrisF - It does.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd cool thanks! and I do see the -2 rep for unaccepting too.

Comment: I raised the flag (or one very similar to it) and I'm glad to see it addressed here - I'd be curious to know what the motivation was. Looking at the user's history there was a serial upvote reversal against them, then they went on an unaccept rampage. What a tedious waste of time.